# PHP File Handling hw

Tags: php, server-side, file-handling, filehandle

```
$handle = fopen("mytext.txt", "r");

echo fread($handle,filesize("mytext.txt"));
echo preg_match("/[0-9]/","",$handle);

fclose($handle);
```

I want to open a text file and find how many digits are there in the text. I tried to use `preg_match` but I think this is  not correct way to do it.

Comment: It looks like your sample code got truncated, can you edit your post to make sure formatting and full listing is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preg_match() accepts Handle for resources. Which is incorrect:

```
$handle = fopen("mytext.txt", "r");

$content = fread($handle,filesize("mytext.txt"));
$noDigit = preg_match("/[0-9]/","",$content);

fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). preg_match() will only match the first result.

Also, your regex is looking for a single numeric value. You should use `\d+` to match all instances of one or more numbers (i.e. matches 1, 20, and 3580243).

```
$subject = "String with numbers 4 8 15 16 23 42";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('\d+', $subject, $matches);
```

Then, to count them, you can just loop through the matches in $matches and increment a counter variable.

EDIT: Also, you'd probably get better results with [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of using fopen, fread, fclose.